# HttpWebRequest get unauthorized exception

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, httpwebrequest

Trying to call a remote server using the following code I get always the unauthorized exception from the server:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest;
var myURI = "https://myURI";
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myURI);

webRequest.Method = "GET";

string myCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("myUsername" + ":" + "myPassword"));
webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + myCredentials);

HttpWebResponse webResponse;
webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

string response = string.Empty;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    response = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
```

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'
>
> WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="geoserver"
>
> Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Set-Cookie: BCSI-CS-**********=1; Path=/
>
> Proxy-Support: Session-based-authentication
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
>
> Content-Length: 23

It is a litte bit weird because, if I try (almost) the same thing via postman, it works and i get the correct response from the remote server (without 401).

I've also tried other ways like the follwing code, but nothing helps:

```
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(
new Uri("https://mywebserver/webpage"), 
"Basic",    //also tried NTLM
new NetworkCredential("user", "password"));
webRequest.Credentials = cc;
```

If I try to call an other server with the same code it works.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the first request from Postman with First request in c#.  Make the c# headers in the request look like postman.  The default headers in c# are different from Postman.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the Exception, has a Session-based-authentication. The problem is: There is no documentation for the reverse proxy and I cannot find an endpoint in order to get a clean cookie. As workaround i've tried the fllowing code and it works now.
It's maybe not the best way to set the Cookie as HttpHeader.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest();
        string cookie = null;

        HttpWebResponse webResponse;
        try
        {
            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            var headers = (WebHeaderCollection)ex.Response.GetType().GetProperty("Headers").GetValue(ex.Response, null);
            cookie = headers.Get("Set-Cookie");
            webRequest = CreateWebRequest();
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie);
            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();
        }


        string response = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            response = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
    }

    private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest;
        var myURI = "https://myURI";
        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myURI);
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        string myCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("myUsername" + ":" + "myPassword"));
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + myCredentials);
        return webRequest;
    }
```